# Swift + Core ML to find similar images from array

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, image-recognition, coreml

I am looking for a way to analyze images in array in find % of similarity in Swift using Core ML.

I have checked some tutorials about Core ML, but still can not understand how and where to start to work on my task. Maybe somebody can gave kind of help

Comment: You want to find images that are similar to a different image or similarity between the rest of the images in the array?

Answer (score 0):

You can train your model or use already trained model. For example [turicreate](https://github.com/apple/turicreate). [Here](https://apple.github.io/turicreate/docs/userguide/image_similarity/export-coreml.html) tutorial how to convert image similarity model to `CoreML`.